# Figuring out how to find two of the zeros for max/min/saddle point problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

I'm doing a problem that asks me to find these things for $f(x,y)=y^3+3x^2y-6x^2-6y^2+2$.

I found $f_x=6xy-12x$ and $f_y=3y^2+3x^2-12y$

And found two of the zeros/points listed in the answer key, $(0,0), (0,4)$.

The book says that points $(1,1), (-1,-1)$ are saddle points but I don't see how they got those x and y values as zeros of the second derivatives. In the case of x=1 and y=1, $f_x=6(1)(1)-12(1)=6-12=-6.$

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Have you found the hessian matrix with respect to this function? What are its eigenvalues when evaluated at $(0,0)$ and $(0,4)$?

Comment: Eigenvalues? I guess I need to look up what a hessian matrix is. Our instructor never mentioned it in the less on these problems.

Comment: How were you taught to determine if the critical points are maxima, minima or saddle points?

Comment: We were shown to finds the zeros like I did, then first plug them into D (D=$f_{xx}*f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2$, if D > 0 then there's an extrema, in D < it's a saddle point. In the case of D > 0 then plug the x and y values of the point int $f_{xx}$ and use it's sign to determine the point is a maximum or minimum.

Comment: Oh, I see, It's exactly the same thing, only your instructor chewed your food and fed it directly into your mouth. OK, and now I realize I misread your question, sorry. Give me a minute.

Comment: Oh. After googling... that's what D is.

Comment: Yea, I've been leaning more from this forum and googling topics than in the class...

Comment: MSE is an amazing place to learn. And the book is wrong. Saddle points are critical points and $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ are not critical points.

Comment: Yea, it is. I've recommended it to quite a few people. Part of what helped me keep my sanity thus few, lol. And, hm alright. Thanks very much for the help. I new I had issues with finding the zeros for these things, but I was hoping I wasn't that bad that I couldn't see it with the answer right in front of me.

Comment: There isn't any way to get any idea how many critical points there are is there? My biggest worry this whole time will that I'll go into a test and miss a few on problems...

Comment: You did miss a couple of points, though. And those might be saddle points. Try $(-2,2)$ and $(2,2)$.

Comment: Yea, tried them and they are. Thanks.

Comment: I hate to ask more after such a drawn thing already, but is $D=-54y+108-36X^2$ correct? I'm getting the correct answers for points (0,0), and the two you gave, but for the (0,4)... book says local min, but $-54(4)-108-36(0)=-216+108-0=-108$ Which would mean a saddle point...

Comment: Doesn't seem correct. There should be a $y^2$ somewhere. Try finding $D$ again. (By the way, this that you call $D$ is just the determinant of the hessian matrix).

Comment: Ok, found the problem. I was doing something stupid with my $f_{yy}$... Whole problem worked out now. Thanks very much for all your help, Git Gud.

Comment: No worries. What would be nice is if now you posted a detailed answer yourself. Pay special attention to how you find the critical points, though. Because you should be able to find them by simple arithmetic alone without anyone having to tell you to try this and that.

Comment: Hmm I will go ahead and do that. In the morning anyway. Far to late here and I'm just likely to make a sloppy post. It'll be good review to write out again later.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. It also gives other people the chance to answer and perhaps give new insight. Good night.

Answer (score 1):

**Finding the Max (downhill in every direction)/Min (uphill in every direction)/Saddle points (down hill along one axis, uphill along the other) for $f(x,y)=y^3+3x^2y-6x^2-6y^2+2$.**

*Equation to test the points you find to see if they are one of the types you are looking for:*

$D$(hessian matrix)$=f_{xx}*f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2$

-> If D > 0 then the point plugged into its equation is an extrema point. If D < 0 then the point is a saddle point. In the case that D is zero, the test is inconclusive.

-> Need $f_x$ an $f_y$ as well to find the critical points.
-> Will use $f+{xx}$ to determine if an extrema point is a maximum point or a minimum point.

*Needed partial derivatives:*

$f_x=6xy-12x$, $f_y=3y^2+3x^2-12y$

$f_{xx}=6y-12$, $f_{yy}=6y-12$

$f_{xy}=6x$

$D=(6y-12)*(6y-12)-(6x)^2$

*Final equation:*

$D=36y^2-144y+144$

*Finding the critical points (those which are candidates for being a max, min, or saddle point):*

->Set $f_x=f_y=0$

$6xy-12x=0$ -----and------ $3y^2+3x^2-12y=0$

-> There is an x or y in every term of both equations.
-> Thus setting both x and y to zero sets both equations to zero.

-> First critical point: **(0,0)**

*Now,*

-> Use left hand side to find a equation for x.

$6xy-12x=0$ -> $6xy=12x$ -> $\frac{12x}{x}=6y$ -> $12=6y$

-> Thus: y=2.
-> Plug y value into right hand side equation.

$3(2^2)+3x^2-12(2)=0$

$12+3x^2-24=0$

$3x^2=12$

-> Thus x = -2 || 2

-> This yields the following critical points: **(-2, 2) and (2, 2).**

*Finally,*

-> Notice that setting x to zero, with any y value makes the left hand equation equal to zero. If x equals zero on the right hand side:

$3y^2+3(0^2)-12y$

$(3y^2-12y)=0$

$3(y^2-4y)=0$ -> $y^2-4y=0$

-> Thus y= 4, yielding the following critical point: (0, 4).

-> Therefore the critical points are: **(0, 0), (0, 4), (2, 2), (-2, 2).**

*Testing the points using the formula for D:*

$D(0, 0)=36(0)^2-144(0)+144=144$

-> D is positive so this is an extrema point. Plug the point into $f_{xx}$.

$f_{xx}(0,0)=6(0)-12=-12$

-> $f_{xx}$ is negative, the slope in all directions from this point goes downwards, so this is a **local max**.

$D(0, 4)=36(4)^2-144(4)+144=144$

-> D is positive so this is an extrema point. Plug the point into $f_{xx}$.

$f_{xx}(0,0)=6(4)-12=18$

-> $f_{xx}$ is positive, the slope in all directions from this point goes upwards, so this is a **local min**.

$D(2, 2)=36(2)^2-144(2)+144=-288$

-> D is negative meaning this is a **saddle point**.

$D(-2, 2)=36(2)^2-144(2)+144=-288$

-> D is negative meaning this is a **saddle point** as well.